# How to open multiple Visual Studio windows on Windows 8.1?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-8.1

I was using Windows 7 and I was able to launch more than one Visual Studio and work at the same time. Now I have windows 8.1 OS and whenever I try to launch second Visual Studio it brings me the one currently launched. Is there a solution for that or should I settle to this new thing?

Comment: Of course you must be able to open as many instances of Visual Studio as you want. Please describe how you are trying to lunch the second one?

Comment: "Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming." I'd say this question does directly involve a tool used primarily for programming.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you have one instance open of Visual Studio, locate it in the taskbar.

Rightclick on the Visual Studio icon and click the line "Visual Studio[version]".

[image: VS]

Answer (score 21):

Middle click your Visual Studio icon in the task bar.

Comment: Nice.. I didn't actually know about this

Answer (score 4):

Press shift and click the visual studio icon